# SVG Featured image not shown in twitter

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, twitter, svg

I have a post with a featured image (size 736x212).
The post url is [this](https://fedetask.com/writing-a-linux-pam-aware-application/).
I shared my post on twitter, but the tweet doesn't show the image (if you want to check [click here](https://twitter.com/fedetask/status/1069657789163819009)).
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Twitter has some limitations upon file extensions. I see that you're passing on some variables within your meta tag.

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/optimize-with-cards/overview/markup.html

> URL of image to use in the card. Images must be less than 5MB in size. JPG, PNG, WEBP and GIF formats are supported. Only the first frame of an animated GIF will be used. SVG is not supported.

Try removing the variables within the image url, it could possibly block twitter from thinking it's a valid image. You could also check the filesize of your image.

Comment: The image is a PNG, size 20Kb so that should not be the problem. How can I remove the variables? I've just added the image in the "featured image" section of the post editor

Comment: Do you have access to the code? You could request the url with the following function: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail_url/

Comment: Here is that function code https://pastebin.com/GTE2drqJ

Answer (score 0):

Checkout Wordpress plugin called [SVG Feature Image](https://github.com/nirus/svg-featured-image) on GitHub.

> #### This plugin is written to convert the SVG featured images to a socially sharable thumbnail images on the fly via Facebook & Twitter.

This is a newly developed plugin & currently under source code review with Wordpress. Meanwhile checkout the project on GitHub.

***It's completely opensource and free.***